# Tiny white spots appearing on mint leaf

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, mint

[image: white spots appearing on several leaves from the mint pot]

I have been keeping this mint plot for several weeks and it has been growing just fine. Yet just today I noticed there's some white spots on some leaves surface, tried to clean with Q-tip but they just stick there.

I'm wondering what has happened and, if I'm going to use those leaves for cooking would that be fine will those spots?

Some information : I grow the mint plant with a pot in the balcony, the weather here is dry and warm with quite a lot of sunlight.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like it's probably damage from thrips. The damage is typically superficial unless you get a bad infestation, although the insects are capable of spreading plant pathogens. The leaf and plants are still fine to use. Thrips tend to favour dryer areas, and plants are typically more affected when they are stressed, e.g. from a lack of consistent watering, but some damage may be unavoidable without the use of pesticide.

Answer (score 1):

[Powdery Mildew](https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/powdery-mildew) Warm and dry are the key words to me.  I think this is the beginning of Powdery Mildew.  Is your balcony covered overhead?

Powdery mildew is a great diagnosis as it is the only fungal infection curable after infection.  Bamboo gave me this little treatment a few years ago and by golly it worked; a 9:1 ratio of water to milk! Cool thing is that this can not hurt your plants so go ahead and try spraying this solution on your plants, now.

Please send another picture or two and one of after spraying...a couple of days after spraying.  A picture of the environment.  More information about the soil in those pots, how they were planted, how long ago, watering habits, fertilizer anything you could imagine really please send along with pictures.
[powdery mildew on maple leaf](https://www.apsnet.org/edcenter/intropp/topics/Article%20Images/defensesfig01.jpg)